# IIS Authorization Not Working During WebRequest to Itself

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I'm having a problem when trying to get an authenticated response in MVC4 on IIS when making a call to itself using the current users credentials.

I'm using the code below. It simply creates a request back to the local server using the port its on to return a given page. Note, changing 'localhost' to `HttpContext.Request.Url.Host` makes no difference.

On my local machine on the Dev Server, this works. 
On my local machine using IIS it doesn't, I get a 401: Unauthorized.

On IIS I have Basic Authentication and ASP.Net Impersonation on, with both     `<authentication mode="Windows" />` and `<identity impersonate="true" />` in the web.config. It's configured like this to ensure that the SQL Server (which is on a different machine) can authenticate correctly.

As the server is calling itself, I don't believe this is the double-hop problem?

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get the request to authenticate against the server using the current users authentication?

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult GetTest()
    {
        try
        {
            string urlAddress = string.Format("http://{0}:{1}/{2}", "localhost", HttpContext.Request.Url.Port, "api/diagnostic/get");

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);
            request.Proxy = null; // Important! Stops the object searching for settings that cause a big slowdown.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            request.PreAuthenticate = true;

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    using (Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        if (receiveStream == null)
                        {
                            throw new Exception("ReceiveStream is null.");
                        }

                        StreamReader readStream = response.CharacterSet == null
                            ? new StreamReader(receiveStream)
                            : new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet));

                        string data = readStream.ReadToEnd();

                        response.Close();
                        readStream.Close();

                        return Content(data);
                    }
                }
            }

            return Content("Error");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return Content(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's likely that your server credentials are not valid. Try another credentials instead of `request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`

Comment: @KhanhTO Thanks, I've added some clarification, I need to make the call using the current users credentials.

Comment: @KhanhTO But it can authenticate against SQL Server, Sharepoint and other services using impersonation but not itself?

Comment: i think you need https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291350(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @KhanhTO I have. I don't see anything in there which helps. Basic authentication is on so that the SQL Server authenticates as the user, however the website cannot query itself as the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the authorisation didn't want to work I had to work around it. As I was requesting data from the same server I didn't need to create a HttpRequest, I could just access the controllers directly.

Obviously its a bit more complicated than a simple WebRequest but it does come with the advantage that the return type is exactly what the controller returns.

The handling of the parameters is probably not complete, but it works for me.

```
        var httpContext =
            new HttpContextWrapper(
                new HttpContext(
                    new HttpRequest(null, "http://servername/api/diagnostic/get", // interestingly the actual servername is not required.
                        "parameter=1&parameter2=foo"),
                    new HttpResponse(new StringWriter())));

        var routeData = RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(httpContext);

        var req = new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData);

        var controller =
            (ControllerBase)
                ControllerBuilder.Current.GetControllerFactory()
                    .CreateController(new RequestContext(httpContext, routeData), routeData.Values["controller"].ToString());

        var context = new ControllerContext(req, controller);

        controller.ControllerContext = context;

        var desc = new ReflectedControllerDescriptor(controller.GetType());

        var action = desc.FindAction(context, routeData.Values["action"].ToString());

        var queryString = httpContext.Request.QueryString;

        var parameters = action.GetParameters()
            .ToDictionary(p => p.ParameterName,
                p =>
                    p.ParameterType.IsEnum
                        ? Enum.ToObject(p.ParameterType, Convert.ChangeType(queryString.GetValues(p.ParameterName)[0], TypeCode.Int32))
                        : Convert.ChangeType(queryString.GetValues(p.ParameterName)[0], p.ParameterType));

        var result = action.Execute(context, parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the validate integrated mode configuration to false.

```
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
```

See this article for an explanation as to why:
http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/validation